# Logstash: how to use syslog_pri plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, syslog, logstash-grok

I'm using [Elastic stack](http://elastic.co). There are a lot of messages which are parsed by my Logstash. I've decided to add some additional rules for Logstash.
I've installed [Syslog pri plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-syslog_pri.html) to my Logstash, because I want to create some mapping for my syslog's severity levels.

All of my messages has `syslog_pri` values according to [RFC-3164](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt), where `error` messages has "(3, 11, 19, ..., 187)" values of `syslog_pri`.

Well, I have two problems:

1) It's not very usable for me, because querying via Kibana is not usable. When I want to filter errors, it looks like:

```
syslog_pri: (3 OR 11 OR 19 OR 27 OR 35 OR 43 OR 51 OR 59 OR 67 OR 75 OR 83 OR 91 OR 99 OR 107 OR 115 OR 123 OR 131 OR 139 OR 147 OR 155 OR 163 OR 171 OR 179 OR 187)
```

but it will be much easier with `syslog_pri` plugin. I expect to have something like this:

```
syslog_pri: "error"
```

Is it possible to create this mapping somehow?

2) I want to change this `syslog_pri` value for some specific messages.
For example, I'm catching message like "Hello world" and want to change the severity from 14 (info messages) into 11 (error message).

I'm doing something like this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "..." }
  }

  syslog_pri { }
  if "Hello world" in [message]
  {
    mutate { syslog_pri => 11 }
  }
```

But this failed with an error:
`logstash.filters.mutate - Unknown setting 'syslog_pri' for mutate`

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To use the `syslog_pri` filter, you simply need to have a field with the value, which in turn will be decoded by the filter. If you have a field which is already named `syslog_pri`, then using it is as simple as putting

```
syslog_pri { }
```

in your logstash configuration.

This plugin will create 4 additional fields which will contain the decoded syslog_pri information:

- syslog_facility
- syslog_severity
- syslog_facility_code
- syslog_severity_code

As for mutating a field the syntax is as follows.

```
mutate {
  replace => { "syslog_pri" => "11"}
}
```